# LEFT OUTER JOIN MySQL query returns empty result set

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables: **s_master**  and **p_master** .

**S_master table**

```
s_id   form_id
----   -------
  1     kit011
  2     kit011
  3     kit011
  4     kit011
  5     kit011
```

**p_master table**

```
s_id   staus
----   -------
  2     1
  3     2
  4     1
```

Problem statement:

I have to fetch **s_id** from **s_master** table which are **NOT** having status **1** in **p_master** table. That means I need to fetch **1,3,5**  .

For this I have used following query.

```
SELECT a.s_id FROM s_master a 
  left outer join p_master b on a.s_id!=b.s_id 
 where  b.status=1 and a.form_id='kit011';
```

But it shows "Empty result set" as result.

Kindly suggest me the query . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way

```
SELECT s.s_id
  FROM s_master s LEFT JOIN p_master p
    ON s.s_id = p.s_id
 WHERE s.form_id = 'kit011' 
   AND (p.s_id IS NULL OR p.status <> 1);
```

or

```
SELECT s_id
  FROM s_master s 
 WHERE form_id = 'kit011'
   AND NOT EXISTS 
 (
   SELECT * 
     FROM p_master
    WHERE s_id = s.s_id AND status = 1
 );
```

Comment: there was typo error in your answer(`s_master` was `s_matser` and `p_master` was `p_matser`) which was giving error. edited to correct it.

Comment: Well, if you want to have output from the first case as you have mentioned above, then you will have to apply order by clause at the end of query

Comment: you don't need order by clause in first case to get the output as shown above? I am surprised by that...

Comment: @BhavikShah Thanks for being thorough but the question is not about the order and the order doesn't always matter. If needed it can be easily applied. The whole purpose of the answer is to show a proper use of outer join. But I removed the output based on your feedback anyway.